# Optimizing webview for d3 charting

Tags: android, d3.js, android-webview

I'm currently integrating custom d3 charts into a webview. There are several animation calls, but they don't appear to run very smooth. At least not as smooth as the iOS webview renders them. Are there any optimizations I could set up to improve the fps?

I've tried the following thus far:

```
webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
mWebview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
mWebview.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
```